# Показать alert с ошибкой или перейти на главную страницу

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть компонент входа на сайт.

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Alert } from './Alert.component';

export const SignInForm = () => {
    const [emails, setEmails] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [data, setData] = useState('');

    const submitForm = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const body = JSON.stringify({
            userEmail: emails,
            userPassword: password,
        });
        const url = 'http://localhost:8081/api/users/signin/';
        const headers = {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        };
        const method = 'POST';
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method,
            body,
            headers,
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
        console.log(data);
    };

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <form>
                {data.err ? <Alert error={data.err} /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="inputEmail">Электронная почта</label>
                    <input .../>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="inputPassword">Пароль</label>
                    <input .../>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={submitForm}>
                    Войдти
                </button>
            </form>
            <div className="pt-4">
                <Link to="/signup">У вас нет аккаунта?</Link>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

Я хочу сделать если в объекте `data` есть поле `err` то вывести `alert`.

```
{data.err ? <Alert error={data.err} /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
```

Но проблема когда страница загружается то я сразу попадаю на главную страницу.

Как можно проверить объект `data` на наличия поля `err` и показать `alert`?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы добавил в state еще одну переменную, например, redirOK, заполнял бы ее в submitForm при успешной авторизации, а в рендер сделал бы так:

```
{this.state.redirOK ? <Redirect to="/" />: '' }
{data.err ? <Alert error={data.err} />: ''}
```

Comment: Я использую функциональные компоненты, я не могу написать так `this.state.....`

Comment: ну так сделай ещё одно состояние `const [redirOK , toggleRedirOK ] = useState(false);`

Comment: Я сделал так, но проблема в то, что когда заходишь на страницу, то сразу попадаешь на главную страницу.

Comment: В `submitForm` после `const data = await response.json();` я добавил `data.err ? setError(true) : setData(data);`, а в компоненте поменял на `{error === true ? <Alert error={data.err} /> : <Redirect to="/" />}`

Comment: Вы неправильно меня поняли. Смысл в том, что вывод сообщения об ошибке должно быть обработано отдельно от обработки редиректа. То, что я написал с использованием this.state, никак не меняет логики :) Перепишите под свой код с использование функционального подхода.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const SignInForm = () => {

const [emails, setEmails] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [data, setData] = useState('');
const [isRedirectOk, toggleIsRedirectOk] = useState(false);

const submitForm = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const body = JSON.stringify({
        userEmail: emails,
        userPassword: password,
    });
    const url = 'http://localhost:8081/api/users/signin/';
    const headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
    };
    const method = 'POST';
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method,
        body,
        headers,
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    setData(data);
    toggleIsRedirectOk(true);
};

return (
    <Fragment>
        <form>
           {!data.err && isRedirectOk ? <Redirect to="/" /> : null}
           {data.err ? <Alert error={data.err} /> : null}

           <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="inputEmail">Электронная почта</label>
                <input .../>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="inputPassword">Пароль</label>
                <input .../>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={submitForm}>
                Войдти
            </button>
        </form>
        <div className="pt-4">
            <Link to="/signup">У вас нет аккаунта?</Link>
        </div>
    </Fragment>
);};
```